# Applescript: Read contents from text file, copy contents to clipboard

Tags: applescript, dropbox, automator, plaintext

I am incredibly new to Applescript, first of all, so bear with me.

I currently have a plain-text file in a Dropbox folder. The file is set to be filled  with text (and only text). I am trying to create an Automator workflow (or an Applescript script) that will read the contents from the text file, and write the contents to the clipboard. This way, I can copy text on my iOS devices, paste them into the plain-text file in Dropbox, and then use my mac (and this script), to paste the text to the mac. Basically, using Dropbox to sync clipboards between OS X and iOS.

I imagine the Applescript can't be more than a few lines, but I haven't found the proper way to write it. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is it about the task that confuses you?  Are you simply new to AppleScript or are you having difficulties with one part of this task?  What have you tried?

Comment: I am simply new to AppleScript. I tried various permutations of just about every code you would find on the first few pages of Google searches, using most combinations of "Applescript", "text", "clipboard". Just a newbie, basically. But all is well now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
set the_file to choose file
set the_text to (do shell script "cat " & quoted form of (POSIX path of the_file))
set the clipboard to the_text
```

or alternately using only AS:

```
set the_file to choose file
set the clipboard to (read the_file)
```

(This second piece of code throws an `End of file` error for me for certain files and I'm not sure why, so I'd use the first one)

Comment: Unreal; I had been trying everything (mind you, everything a newb could find on Google..) and coming up with crazy "file does not exist" errors.

Comment: I ultimately used your top code, but changed 'choose file' to 'My:Path:Here.txt'.

Comment: @user2690304 a little late now, but if you're using the first and you know the path, you can just do `set the clipboard to (do shell script "cat /My/Path/Here.txt")`. Most of the complicated parts there is converting from the AS path that `choose file` returns into the POSIX path for bash.

Answer (score 5):

In Automator, you can combine the actions:

1. Files & Folders › Get specified Finder items
2. Text › Combine text files<sup>†</sup>
3. Utilities › Copy to clipboard

to achieve what you're after. You may also want to skip "Get specified Finder items" and instead make your Automator workflow a Folder Action, which will pass files into your workflow as they are added to a folder you specify.

Separately, there may be a better way overall to achieve your end goal. What are you really after? (See [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).)

<sup><sub>† Despite the name, "Combine text files" can be used to read the contents of a single file. It takes one or more files as input and gives rich text as output.</sub></sup>

Comment: great note about the Combine Text Files action working on a single file

Comment: This almost worked - seems that "Combine Text Files" only takes in files with a .txt extension.  Looking for something to raw copy any file extension.

Answer (score 1):

Extending duozmo's solution keeping points #2 & 3 same. Ideally, make an automator service so that it is available upon right clicking single or multiple files.

Here is the screenshot of such a service:

[image]